# Celery periodic task timing error

Tags: python, cron, celery

Currently I have celery periodic-task with the following set-up:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-celery': {
        'task': 'flask_react_app.task.ingest_stock_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/17', hour='8-16', day_of_week='mon-fri'),
    }
}
```

This is almost what I wanted, except, I want the job to start at 08:01 and the finish at 16:30 running every 17 minutes between those times (so 08:01, 08:18, 08:35). So I tried:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-celery': {
        'task': 'flask_react_app.task.ingest_stock_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='1/17', hour='8-16', day_of_week='mon-fri'),
    }
}
```

Which gave me the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid weekday literal '1/17'
```

Even though this literal is in the minute key word argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can do the following if you want to run the task periodically every 1 minute, between 8 and 16.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test-celery': {
        'task': 'flask_react_app.task.ingest_stock_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1', hour='8-16', day_of_week='mon-fri'),
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question for some clarity (I hope). I want the task to run at 08:01, 08:18, 08:35... Up until 16:30 (Or as close as 17 minute intervals will allow).

Comment: Oh I see, You have 2 options, this might and might not work for you `*/17+1` or this `1-59/17`. This works when using cronjobs in general, so  I can't guarantee it will work with python's crontab's module.